# timer / stopwatch for automation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a circular gauge(progress bar) with a polygon needle that when i select a number in a list box the needle goes up to that degree to resemble a speed in a car(works just fine)

What i want to do is automatically run through the indexes of the list items(0,1,2,3,....60) so the needle slowly rises till it gets to say 60 speed. Then, hold that for as long as i want so i can move a tack needle and run an odometer accordingly. i have tried to use a timer in a MVC class and use a stop watch.  I can select the index 0 -6 but it will only just jump to the last one. I am trying to simulate a car dashboard the best i can...What are your thought?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //DispatcherTimer timer;
    List<Double> _items = new List<Double>();


    DispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.ItemsSource = new List<double>() { 0,1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 };
        checkBox1.IsChecked = true;
        park.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2500);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();


    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        int second = DateTime.Now.Second;

         firstDigitsec = second / 10;


        int secondDigitsec = second % 10;


        checkBox1.IsChecked = false;
        first.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
        park.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        checkBox2.IsChecked = true;



       Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

       listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
       listBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
       listBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
       listBox1.SelectedIndex = 3;


    }




    private int _stopw;
    public int sw
    {
        get { return _stopw; }
        set
        {
            _stopw = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("");

        }
    }



    private int _firstDigitsec;
    public int firstDigitsec
    {
        get { return _firstDigitsec; }
        set
        {
            _firstDigitsec = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("");
            /*
             if (firstDigitsec < 1)
             {
                 listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
             }
             if (firstDigitsec < 2)
             {

             */
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using WPF this sounds like an excellent candidate for [Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)

Use a Binding to bind your Gauge's Progress property to the Progress property in your viewmodel and apply a DoubleAnimation to animate the Progress property from the previous value to the new value

Comment: I looke dover the article. This looks like something that will work

Comment: The polygon is my needle but i cant access it from within the progress bar. how can i bind the a progress property?

Comment: I'm assuming your gauge control has some sort of Progress or Value property that you can databind a Progress property in your ViewModel to. If you're creating a gauge by hand you may want to consider some sort of 3rd party library gauge to simplify things. Infragistics offers many gauges